# How to capture characters after last pattern occurrence with regex?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I am currently matching the last occurance of pattern using this:

```
__(?:.(?!__+))+$
```

where the pattern is "__"

However, I need to match the characters after the pattern and not the pattern itself.

for instance, given the string `my__field__name__options`

I need to capture "options" but the regex above captures "__options".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without lookahead you may use this regex in PHP:

```
.*__\K.+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u4ZoTv/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
.*   # match zero or more characters (greedy match)
__   # match "__"
\K   # reset matched info
.+   # match 1 or more characters (greedy)
```

Comment: or just `__([^_]+)$`

Comment: Yes that will also work fine but `.*__\K.+` takes less # of steps to return the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
.*__(.+)
```

.* matches any text, if any
__ matches __ (not greedy)
(.+) matches and captures () any text

https://regex101.com/r/bus5vi/1